# Error after updating

Tags: 8, entities, updating

I recently updated to Drupal 8.2.0 from 8.0. Updating was successful, but the *Status report* page shows this error.

[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute `drush entity-updates`. As usual, test this on non-production system.